# React Formik Default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React formik. I have a dropdown select option. Option is working fine but i want to have default value as Free from the dropdown. If i submit the form without click, it is giving me the option value as blank.
Below is my code:

```
const defautValue="Free";
const options=["Premium","Gold","Free"]


<Field> 
  {(props: any)=>{
    const {field}=props;
    const defaultOption=<option key='default' value={defaultValue}>{defaultValue}</option>
    const option=options.map((i:string)=>{return (<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)})
    const selectOptions=[defaultOption,...option]
    return (
       <div>
       <select value={field.value}{...field}>{selectOptions}</select>
       </div>
         )
  }}
</Field>
```

Answer (score 11):

you can set `enableReinitialize` option to true

your formik hook

```
const formik = useFormik({
        enableReinitialize: true,
        initialValues: $yourState
})
```

Comment: This could be a real problem specifically when you have lots of inputs. this could make your form to re-initiate by every key stroke happens in your inputs;

Answer (score 7):

try removing the manual setting of the defaultOption, selectOptions, and use either the `formik.values`, or `form.value`, and set the `defaultValue` of a component using the `initialValues` of the `Formik` component:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{selectedOption: "Free"}: YourFormData}
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {console.log(values, actions)}}
>
  {formik => (
    <Form translate="yes">
      <Field name="selectedOption">
          {({ form, field }: FieldProps<YourFormData>) => {
          const options=["Premium","Gold","Free"].map((i:string)=>{return (<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>)})    
          return (
             <div>
                 <select {...field}>{options}</select>
             </div>
               )
        }}
      </Field>
    </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

the `{...field}` spread operator of field already has the "value" added

`<Field name="selectedOption">` automagically connects the `selectedOption` formik field up to the `<select>` element, including `onChange`, `onBlur`, `touched`, etc.

Or you can also use `as` for example:

```
<Formik
    initialValues={{selectedOption: 'Free'}}
    onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }, 1000);
    }}>{(props: FormikProps<any>) => (
    <Form>
        <Field as="select" name="selectedOption">
           {["Premium","Gold","Free"].map((i:string)=>(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>))}
        </Field>
    </Form>
)}
</Formik>
```

docs:

- https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field

Answer (score 3):

<Formik

```
    enableReinitialize // missing piece!!
    initialValues={props.initialValues}
```

working here

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `option` that is 'disabled' above the options that you are populating dynamically:

```
<Formik>
 <option disabled value="">(Make a Selection)</option>
 {(props: any)=>{
 //...

</Formik>
```

It will display as the first default option with a message of your choice, and the user won't be able to select it from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

off course you can set `enableReinitialize: true`, but (as i said in a comment) this approach could cause performance problems specifically when you have many inputs.

on the other hand setting `defaultValue` for select or giving `selected={true}` to an option may produce errors.

better way to solve this issue is to set your form value when you fetch your data from server. you can do this after fetching the data or inside a `useEffect` code:

```
if (data.data.length) {
    form.setFieldValue('city', data.data[0].id.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your key to 'default' but your value and innerHTML to {defaultValue} which I don't see defined anywhere. This could cause the blank if defaultValue is undefined.

Also you overwrote defaultOption in your inner scope because it is already defined in the outer scope

Comment: sorry, typos error. Please review the updated one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

Here is what worked.

[Formik API setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void)

So if you have a custom component that is getting initial values but your changing that say from a backend call, you'd use setFieldValue to get the field value updated from the initial one.

In my case, the drop down would have the initial value. It would not update unless I clicked it. I wanted the initialValue to change and this is how I did it.

```js
<Field className='col form-control form-control-sm' id='department' name='department'>
                                {
                                    (props) => {
                                        const { field, form, meta } = props
                                        return (
                                            <DepartmentList field={field} form={form} hotelId={form.values.hotelId} />
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            </Field>
```

Inside that component, where relevant, change the FieldValue of department like this:

```
this.props.form.setFieldValue('department', this.state.department[0].id)
```